# MultiLanguage Web App and Data Caching From a Table

Tags: asp.net, nhibernate, asp.net-mvc-2, caching, fluent

We are developing a multi-language web application with ASP.NET MVC 2 and Fluent NHibernate.
Our platform will be multi-language. But just static text will be multi-language. Groups pages depends on community content whatever they use. Like Facebook.

We decide to keep all language string in database. And load language when application starts.

Is this the best practice ?
What is the best practice for this situation?
How can I cache these text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I implement a database based language feature. Three tables.

- Language
- Language Raw Text
- Language Translated Text

and also implemented a php like code based solution for get and setting text.

For expanded php example for my implementation [click here](http://mel.melaxis.com/devblog/2005/08/06/localizing-php-web-sites-using-gettext/).

Answer (score 1):

If you are not changing the strings with the application running, just keep them in a static dictionary.

Otherwise, read http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#performance-cache through http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#performance-querycache